# Element shown all the time with scrollable ActionBar

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I have activity showing list of elements to allow user select one of them. This activity (same as every other activity in the app) has `ActionBar` with activity title. This bar is scrollable, so when user scrolls down throught the list, it dissapears to show more elements on screen. I like this feature but I need to add `CheckBox` at the end of screen. Right know, after activity start, it is shown just below the screen and user has to scroll down to see it. Is it possible to make the checkbox shown from the start and only the list expandable to the space of `ActionBar`?

Activity after start where Checkbox is invisible below screen:
[image: Activity after start where Checkbox is invisible below screen]

Activity after scrolling down:

[image: Activity after scrolling down]

Expected result - checkbox shown from start

[image: Expected result]

My layout code is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edSearch"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSearchClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnShowOnlyAvailable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chbShowOnlyAvailable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/title_show_only_available"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` , Currently you are using `LinearLayout` (all items are in linear fashion i.e below each other).

Comment: Thanks for advice. I tried to rewrite the layout into `ConstraintLayout` with the `CheckBox` constraint to parent bottom, but the behavior is stil the same

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and set the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` parameter to `true` for your View

Something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout -->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edSearch"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSearchClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- height edited to "match_parent", weight removed-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/pnSearch"/>

    <!-- layout_alignParentBottom parameter added  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnShowOnlyAvailable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chbShowOnlyAvailable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/title_show_only_available"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```